# ConEmu commands in task

Tags: batch-file, conemu

I'm trying to get a Task in ConEmu to open several consoles, and for each run a batch-like script when opened. For example:

- Open a Git Bash, name the console "X", set the current directory to "Y".
- Open another Git Bash and run a set of commands, for example "cd A/B/C", "vagrant up"
- Open a regular command window, run the command "cd D/E/F", "grunt watch"

I want the second and third consoles to appear alongside each other, but underneath the first console. So far I am stuck getting commands to run; I have a task that runs the following:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i "-cur_console:n:t:Git Bash" "-cur_console:d:C:\Users\Ole Vik\dev"
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i "-cur_console:s1TVn:t:Vagrant"
cmd "-cur_console:s2THn:t:Third"
```

Reading the ConEmu [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/TableOfContents?tm=6) led me to the new_console and cur_console [switches](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/NewConsole), but I'm having trouble figuring out if I can somehow enter commands in the Task setup, or maybe if I can have it run a .bat script on each console.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No colon is needed between switches (`n` & `t` for example).

`cmd` has `/k` switch to run commands.

I don't know the way to tell bash "run this command and stay in prompt". May be you need to run commands with `&`. I'm not sure about second line, you need to check it yourself.

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i "-cur_console:nt:Git Bash" "-cur_console:d:C:\Users\Ole Vik\dev"
cmd -cur_console:s1TVnt:Vagrant /c vagrant up & "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"
cmd -cur_console:s2THnt:Third /k cd /d "D\E\F" & grunt watch
```

Comment: Implicitly you highlighted the issue I was having: Getting Bash to behave as I expect cmd to. A quick rewrite using your examples made it possible to run everything I needed using just shell, but keeping the git bash for a few tasks that had to be done manually anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your updated ConEmu task for the benefit of others  trying to accomplish something similar to what you did?

Comment: There's a `-c` command for `bash.exe` that will run a command but unfortunately keep the terminal in interactive mode after. There's also [this solution](https://serverfault.com/a/586272/207363) by using an `--init-file` but I could not get this to work. @OleVik if you're still alive, can you come back and comment :3?

Comment: Several ways are possible: https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinStartCmd.html