# Conemu Task with Added Command

Tags: git, bash, conemu

I'm trying to add a command to the startup tasks in ConEmu that is invoked in Git Bash. I found a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21803819/1148107) that appears to suggest that I can do this, but when I try this it doesn't work and tells me /k or /c is not a file or directory, also it appears to use cmd and I'd like to run this in bash not the command prompt.  Is it possible to set this in a task using ConEmu Git Bash? Something like this that opens up three consoles and begins invoking a couple commands in two of them:

```
%ConEmuDir%\..\Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i 
-new_console:C:"%ConEmuDir%\..\Git\etc\git.ico" 
-cur_console:t:"APP" 
-cur_console:d:D:/projects/mycurrentproject

%ConEmuDir%\..\Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i 
-new_console:C:"%ConEmuDir%\..\Git\etc\git.ico" 
-cur_console:s50H 
-cur_console:t:"GIT" /k "git status"

%ConEmuDir%\..\Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i 
-new_console:C:"%ConEmuDir%\..\Git\etc\git.ico" 
-cur_console:s50V 
-cur_console:t:"Homestead" /k "homestead up"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not related to ConEmu. Bash has no switch to run commands and leave interactive shell running.

The only workaround I know is to set some environment variable to the desired list if commands and and corresponding lines checking and executing it to your profile script.

The same question with some examples is here: https://superuser.com/a/344486/139371

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm not sure I understand your workaround.  Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: Link to similar question added